# status : 500 Internal Server Error postman only posts empty curly brackets when enter the data on the body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

and this is my code (index.js), (auth.js)

```js
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const app = express();

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  }).then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("err"));
app.use("/api/auth",authRoute );

app.use("/api/auth",authRoute);


app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("Backend is running.");
});
```

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN


module.exports = router;
and image of the postman result
```

when I  send the request postman posts empty curly brackets. I want to get the post data on the down of the body at the postman

[screenshot of the postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb7J1.jpg)

and this is what terminal logs
[result on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Q7o.png)

Comment: It looks like you're getting a 500 error, so something in the `try` block is failing.

Comment: still, i can't figure out the issue inside in the **try** block can you make it clear, please

Comment: can you add console.log(err) in the try catch and see what is the error

Comment: As Alan already said there is something throwing an error inside the try block. It's probably either `new User(...)` or `newUser.save()`. Is the user created when making the request to that endpoint?

Comment: When you console.log(req.body), what shows?\

Comment: on the terminal, logs err below the port listen and mongoose connection

Comment: When is `"err"` being logged? Directly or after hitting the endpoint?

Comment: when I hit the endpoint terminal logs the input from the postman and the postman still posts empty curly brackets with 500 status code

Comment: @khaliddahir The 500 error comes from your catch block. So I ask myself: are you still connected to the db when making the request?, as your terminal screenshot shows the string `"err"` which is printed when the connection breaks for some reason. And what are you calling `new User(...)` with? Can you please provide info about `req.body`.

Comment: @Palladium02 as you said the connection on the dp was the issue but the main was the .env file located outside of the project root I moved it from the outside and put inside the project  root  folder and  now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.env file must be inside the root folder, not the outside

Answer (score 1):

You should check what receives in `user` object at  `const user = await newUser.save();`

data would be in `user.data`

or use `json` instead,

```
 const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).jsonp(user);
```

Comment: data shows only the terminal when I log ` console.log(req.body); ` but the postman post empty brackets with 500 status code

Comment: Change contentType to applicatoin/json in post man request instead of raw

Answer (score 0):

I got that error in postman and my problem was that I was adding a str data in an int field in pgAdmin